# search keywords in google through c# window application

Tags: c#, window

i want to work on a scraper program which will search keyword in google. i have problem in starting my scraper program.
my problem is:
let suppose window application(c#) have 2 textboxes and a button control.  first textbox have "www.google.com" and the 2nd textbox contain keywork for example:

textbox1: www.google.com
textbox2: "cricket"

i want code to add to the button click event that will search cricket in google. if anyone have a programing idea in c# then plz help me.

best regards

Comment: This doesnt reflect very much work, try following [this tutorial](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2165-how-to-search-google-and-bing-in-c/). (first result in google)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have googled my problem and found solution to the above problem...
we can use google API for this purpose...when we add reference to google api then we will add the following namespace in our program...........

```
using Google.API.Search;
```

write the following code in button click event

```
var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");
var results = client.Search("google api for .NET", 100);
foreach (var webResult in results)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", webResult.Title, webResult.Url, webResult.Content);
    listBox1.Items.Add(webResult.ToString ());
}
```

test my solution and give comments .........thanx everybody

Comment: bad documentation and features.. they didn't update it for 4 years! according to google, it's "Deprecated". Now you can use Custom Search API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: Which package is needed for this? GoogleApi by Michael Vivet? Google.Apis by Google? Or...?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Paqogomez that you don't appear to have put much work into this but I also understand that it can be hard to get started. Here is some sample code that should get you on the right path.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uriString = "http://www.google.com/search";
    string keywordString = "Test Keyword";

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
    nameValueCollection.Add("q", keywordString);

    webClient.QueryString.Add(nameValueCollection);
    textBox1.Text = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);
}
```

This code will search for "Test Keyword" on Google and return the results as a string.

The problems with what you are asking is Google is going to return your result as HTML that you will need to parse. I really think you need to do some research on the Google API and what is needed to programmatically request data from Google. Start your search here [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/).

Hope this helps get you started on the right path.

Comment: Definitely use the Google API. Scraping Google result pages is a fool's errand, as they're packed with Javascript and the format tends to change distressingly often. Plus, Google will block your IP if they detect you hitting them too often with an automated tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WebClient` class and `DownloadString` method
for searches. Use the regex for matching urls from result string.

For example:

```
WebClient Web = new WebClient();
string Source=Web.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?client=" + textbox2.text);
Regex regex =new Regex(@“ ^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w%&=])?$”);
MatchCollection Collection=regex.Matches(source);
List<string> Urls=new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Collection)
{
    Urls.Add(match.ToString());
}
```