# Automating Google Submits

Tags: c#, php

I need to retrieve company names from a file and do the following for each:

*Submit company name to the search window on the Google home page.

> Example: "Action Motivation, Inc. South San Francisco, CA"

*Read into memory the first search result:
Example:

> Action Motivation, Inc.
>   www.amotive.com/‎
>   Provides corporate and special event planning and conference management services. South San Francisco, CA.
>   Google+ page · Be the first to review
>   400 San Francisco (Oyster Point) - Oakland, S San Francisco, CA 94080
>   (650) 416-2400

*Grab the company's url from this result, "www.amotive.com", and submit that to the Google search window.

*Read into memory the 10 search results returned.

*Advance to the next results page and read the next 10 returns.

*Put all scraped data into SQL Server.

I'm comfortable with C# and SQL Server but haven't done any web programming yet. I'd like to know what language(s) I'll need to automate this process. I'm NOT looking for the "best" language but rather what the *basics* would be for a newbie like myself to automate this task.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Google API. My bad, I should have researched this better before posting.
[search keywords in google through c# window application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389714/search-keywords-in-google-through-c-sharp-window-application)