# Console based web crawler using Google search bar C#

Tags: c#, search, web-crawler

I'm attempting to write a console based web crawler using `C#` and want to be able to use Googles search bar and search a key word, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389714/search-keywords-in-google-through-c-sharp-window-application). But that is using a Windows app, so I'm thinking it's different from console based..? How can I go about this in a sufficient easy manner, is it the same concept as using the Windows App?

Source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Crawler
{

    //Create information handling

    public interface IWidow
    {
        string Say(string input);
        string Success(string input);
        string MinorErr(string input);
        string FatalErr(string input);
        string Debug(string input);
    }

    /*
     * Intiate the information handling
     * and create the color coordination.
     */

    public class ConsoleInformative : IWidow
    {
        public string Say(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {input}");
            return input;
        }

        public string Success(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {input}");
            return input;
        }

        public string MinorErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {input}");
            return input;
        }

        public string FatalErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {input}");
            return input;
        }

        public string Debug(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")}] {input}");
            return input;
        }
    }

    class BlackWidow
    {

        /*
         * Make a request to the web host in
         * this case it is Google.
         */

        private static string GetWebInfo(string url)
        {
            string logPath = $@"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)}\log\html.txt";
            string errPath = $@"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)}\log\error.txt";

            HttpWebRequest requests = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            requests.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

            IWebProxy proxy = requests.Proxy;
            IWidow info = new ConsoleInformative();

            /*
             * Used cached credentials to access
             * proxy if there is one.
             */

            info.Say("Checking if you're behind a proxy");
            if (proxy != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    info.Say("Proxy found attempting to login with cached credentials..");
                    string proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(requests.RequestUri).ToString();
                    requests.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    requests.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false);
                    requests.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                }

                /*
                 * Catch exception if hte cached
                 * credentials fail to load.
                 */

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    info.FatalErr("Unable to verify cached credentials..");
                    File.WriteAllText($"{errPath}", e.ToString());
                    info.Debug("Wrote error to file for further analysis, exiting process..");
                }
            }
            info.Success("Logged in with cached credentials, continuing process.");
            WebResponse providedResponse = requests.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = providedResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readInformation = new StreamReader(stream);
            string htmlOutput = readInformation.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText($"{logPath}", htmlOutput);
            return htmlOutput;
        }

        //Main method

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWidow info = new ConsoleInformative();

            try
            {
                string searchQuery = "test";
                string searchEngine = "https://google.com";
                NameValueCollection search = new NameValueCollection();
                Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                info.Say("Attempting to connect to the site..");
                GetWebInfo(searchEngine);
                info.Success($"Connected to site, writing HTML to file, and searching {searchEngine} with query {searchQuery}.");
                search.Add("q", searchQuery);
            }

            /*
             * Catch all exceptions and write them
             * to a file for futher analysis if any
             * occur during the process.
             */

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                info.FatalErr($"Exception thrown: {e}");
                File.WriteAllText($@"{filePath}\errorlog.LOG", e.ToString());
                info.Debug($"Wrote Exception to file located in {filePath}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at my implementation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16975398/1610747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below runs in a console application, but I getting a proxy error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Crawler
{
        //Create information handling

    public interface IWidow
    {
        string Say(string input);
        string Success(string input);
        string MinorErr(string input);
        string FatalErr(string input);
        string Debug(string input);
    }

    /*
     * Intiate the information handling
     * and create the color coordination.
     */

    public class ConsoleInformative : IWidow
    {
        public string Say(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}",DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"),input);
            return input;
        }

        public string Success(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"), input);
            return input;
        }

        public string MinorErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"), input);
            return input;
        }

        public string FatalErr(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"), input);
            return input;
        }

        public string Debug(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}",DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"), input);
            return input;
        }
    }

    public class BlackWidow
    {
        public BlackWidow(string url)
        {
            GetWebInfo(url);
        }

        /*
         * Make a request to the web host in
         * this case it is Google.
         */

        private static string GetWebInfo(string url)
        {
            string logPath = string.Format(@"{0}\html.txt", Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
            string errPath = string.Format(@"{0}\error.txt", Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));

            HttpWebRequest requests = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            requests.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            requests.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

            IWebProxy proxy = requests.Proxy;
            IWidow info = new ConsoleInformative();

            /*
             * Used cached credentials to access
             * proxy if there is one.
             */

            info.Say("Checking if you're behind a proxy");
            if (proxy != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    info.Say("Proxy found attempting to login with cached credentials..");
                    string proxyUri = proxy.GetProxy(requests.RequestUri).ToString();
                    requests.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    requests.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false);
                    requests.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                }

                /*
                 * Catch exception if hte cached
                 * credentials fail to load.
                 */

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    info.FatalErr("Unable to verify cached credentials..");
                    File.WriteAllText(errPath, e.ToString());
                    info.Debug("Wrote error to file for further analysis, exiting process..");
                }
            }
            info.Success("Logged in with cached credentials, continuing process.");
            WebResponse providedResponse = requests.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = providedResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readInformation = new StreamReader(stream);
            string htmlOutput = readInformation.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(logPath, htmlOutput);
            return htmlOutput;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWidow info = new ConsoleInformative();

            try
            {
                string searchQuery = "test";
                string searchEngine = "https://google.com";
                NameValueCollection search = new NameValueCollection();
                Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                info.Say("Attempting to connect to the site..");
                BlackWidow blackWidow = new BlackWidow(searchEngine);
                info.Success(string.Format("Connected to site, writing HTML to file, and searching {0} with query {1}.", searchEngine,searchQuery));
                search.Add("q", searchQuery);

            }


            /*
             * Catch all exceptions and write them
             * to a file for futher analysis if any
             * occur during the process.
             */

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                info.FatalErr(string.Format("Exception thrown: {0}", e.ToString()));
                File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"{0}\errorlog.LOG",filePath), e.ToString());
                info.Debug(string.Format("Wrote Exception to file located in {0}",filePath));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not behind a proxy, you can take out the proxy part. It's mostly just for where I am located