# anyway i could make my Speech Recognition App search google?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

i've been working on a personal assistant project, so far its going great but i dont know how to make her do a google search.
here's what i've tried :

```
            if (speech == "friday search google")
            {
                Friday.SpeakAsync("what are you searching for?");
               //theoratically speaking the next line should be the problem, i need a string that 
               //starts recording audio so i can recall the recorded audio as the named string (search)
                SpeechRecognitionEngine search = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();   // <-- this line
                string url = "www.google.com/search?=q";
                Process.Start(url + search);
            }
```

or if im entirely wrong, i'd really appreciate some help into making it work.
thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: so your question really is 'how can i convert captured speech to text'?

Comment: Process.Start is OS dependent. Since you are using C#, can we assume you are using Windows?

Comment: does this help at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389714/search-keywords-in-google-through-c-sharp-window-application

Comment: and of course this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8 but its seems you know this class exists but are not trying to use it

Comment: @pm100 yes if im able to convert the captured speech then i could get my code running, i just don't know how to.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz my OS is Windows, correct.